# The Restart problem for a variable with a loop

Tags: vb.net

I want a loop to display the values where values ​​are required to be repeated. Take numbers from 0 to 9 after every 10 numbers starting from zero and 1 2 3

my code

```vb
For i = 0 To 200
    If i > 10 Then
        i = 0
        listbox.Items.Add(i)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
For i = 0 To 199
    ListBox1.Items.Add(i Mod 10)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inside an infinite loop as you return back when `i` becomes > `10`
A way to achieve your goal is:

```
    Dim steps As Integer = 2
    Dim range As Integer = 10
    Dim ind As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To (steps * range) - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To range - 1
            ind += 1
            Console.WriteLine(ind)
            listbox.Items.Add(i)
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: The loop is not correct, it gives the number of rows 2211, and it should only be 200

Comment: Was only a simply demonstration, obviously you had to change in base of you exigences.
However I’ve update the answer